# C# Threading : Threads executed on incorrect object

Tags: c#, multithreading

Probably this is a dumb mistake by me, but I can't figure it out.

So the scenario is that I retrieve a record from a database every 200ms, if there is one available.
On each record, I start a thread.
In this case it's a mail that is sent.

```
    QMail mailRecord;

    while (!stopSending)
    {

        if (QueueMailingHandler.m_numActive >= MaxThreads)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            continue;
        }

        mailRecord = QMail.Next();

        if (mailRecord.UID > 0)
        {
            QueueMailingHandler.m_numActive++;

            QueueMailingHandler MailingHandler = new QueueMailingHandler();

            mailRecord.Processing = true;

            MailingHandler.Start(mailRecord);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
```

My MailingHandler:

```
internal QueueMailingHandler()
{
}

internal void Start(QMail rec)
{
    record = rec;
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessThread));

    thread.IsBackground = true;

    thread.Start();
}

public void ProcessThread()
{
    _logging = new AutoQueueLog(record.UID.ToString(), "Sending Mails", record.Subject, "Processing");
    _logging.Path = @"C:\Windows Services\QueueMailing\AutoLog";
    _logging.LogMessage();
    try
    {

        SendMail(record);
        record.SetDone();
        _logging.State = "Done";
        _logging.LogMessage();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logging.State = "Error";
        _logging.LogException = ex;
        _logging.Level = AutoLog.ExceptionLevel.Major;
        _logging.LogMessage();
    }
    finally
    {
        m_numActive--;
    }
}
```

And as loggingresult, I get this:

```
6/16/2015 11:57:02 AM - [328] - Function : QueueMailingHandler.ProcessThread() - Processing
6/16/2015 11:57:02 AM - [329] - Function : QueueMailingHandler.ProcessThread() - Processing
6/16/2015 11:57:02 AM - [329] - Function : QueueMailingHandler.ProcessThread() - Done
6/16/2015 11:57:02 AM - [330] - Function : QueueMailingHandler.ProcessThread() - Done
6/16/2015 11:57:02 AM - [330] - Function : QueueMailingHandler.ProcessThread() - Processing
6/16/2015 11:57:02 AM - [331] - Function : QueueMailingHandler.ProcessThread() - Processing
6/16/2015 11:57:02 AM - [331] - Function : QueueMailingHandler.ProcessThread() - Done
6/16/2015 11:57:03 AM - [332] - Function : QueueMailingHandler.ProcessThread() - Processing
6/16/2015 11:57:03 AM - [333] - Function : QueueMailingHandler.ProcessThread() - Processing
6/16/2015 11:57:03 AM - [333] - Function : QueueMailingHandler.ProcessThread() - Done
6/16/2015 11:57:03 AM - [333] - Function : QueueMailingHandler.ProcessThread() - Done
6/16/2015 11:57:03 AM - [333] - Function : QueueMailingHandler.ProcessThread() - Done
```

The question is: Why are my threads using objects that should be in a seperate (yet similar) thread?

Any help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I'd be glad to help, but what's your question exactly?

Comment: I'm almost sure, the error is in your `record = rec;` line. You want to copy your object, but you just copy a reference to the original one, so the next `record = rec;` will overwrite the last one. Could you try to call the copy contructor on `rec`?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but threads are really low level. Most of the time it is much better to use some higher level construct like tasks or async and await. In particular, each thread in a 32 bit process will by default consume 1 MB of virtual address space for the stack so a thousand threads will consume 1 GB of virtual address space. And with 2 GB reserved for the OS you can easily exhaust your memory.

Comment: In your case, your "record" variable is not thread-safe which causes unexpected behaviour. record object is refereneced from all the active threads. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) learn about thread safety.

Comment: @Martin: I have tried TPL, but that gave a lot of errors on deploying it into a Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using the same shared instance of `record` for all your threads.

An easy way to fix the issue is to use a parameter when starting your thread:

```
internal void Start(QMail rec)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ProcessThread));

    thread.IsBackground = true;

    thread.Start(rec);
}
```

Then, in the thread, use the parameter instead of the property:

```
public void ProcessThread(object parameter)
{
    var record = (QMail)parameter;

    _logging = new AutoQueueLog(record.UID.ToString(), "Sending Mails", record.Subject, "Processing");
    _logging.Path = @"C:\Windows Services\QueueMailing\AutoLog";
    _logging.LogMessage();
    try
    {

        SendMail(record);
        record.SetDone();
        _logging.State = "Done";
        _logging.LogMessage();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logging.State = "Error";
        _logging.LogException = ex;
        _logging.Level = AutoLog.ExceptionLevel.Major;
        _logging.LogMessage();
    }
    finally
    {
        m_numActive--;
    }
}
```

Also, decreasing the `m_numActive` counter that way will give unpredictable results. You should use a thread-safe way, such as the `Interlock.Decrement` method:

```
Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_numActive);
```

Last but not least, you should consider using the thread pool instead of creating a new thread every time:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessThread, rec);
```

Comment: Allright, seems like this Start() function is doing the trick.
But you're suggesting that I use the ThreadPool instead of the Threads here. What is the adventage and will the Interlocked.Increment / Decrement still work?

Comment: @Devcon2 The thread pool is a set of thread managed directly by the .NET runtime. It's adapted for short tasks before threads are created proactively (thus saving the creation delay when starting the task), and the number of active threads is adapted to best fit the machine ressources. Interlocked.Increment/Decrement are just thread-safe ways to manipulate number, so it isn't impact by whether you created the thread manually or using the thread pool

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
 QMail mailRecord;

while (!stopSending)
{

    if (QueueMailingHandler.m_numActive >= MaxThreads)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        continue;
    }

    mailRecord = QMail.Next();

    if (mailRecord.UID > 0)
    {
        QueueMailingHandler.m_numActive++;

        QueueMailingHandler MailingHandler = new QueueMailingHandler();

        mailRecord.Processing = true;

        MailingHandler.Start(mailRecord);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(200);
}
```

Try this

```
while (!stopSending)
{

    if (QueueMailingHandler.m_numActive >= MaxThreads)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        continue;
    }

    QMail mailRecord = QMail.Next();

    if (mailRecord.UID > 0)
    {
        QueueMailingHandler.m_numActive++;

        QueueMailingHandler MailingHandler = new QueueMailingHandler();

        mailRecord.Processing = true;

        MailingHandler.Start(mailRecord);
    }

    Thread.Sleep(200);
}
```

The only difference here is where you declare your QMail instance.